# IndexError: String Index out of range for recursive function

Tags: python, string, recursion

So I am learning python and am trying to count the number of vowels in a sentence. I figured out how to do it both using the count() function and an iteration but now I am trying to do it using recursion. When I try the following method I get an error "IndexError: string index out of range". Here is my code.

```
sentence = input(": ")

def count_vowels_recursive(sentence):
    total = 0
    if sentence[0] == "a" or sentence[0] == "e" or sentence[0] == "i" or sentence[0] == "o" or sentence[0] == "u":
        total = total + 1 + count_vowels_recursive(sentence[1:])
    else:
        total = total + count_vowels_recursive(sentence[1:])   
    return the_sum

print(count_vowels_recursive(sentence))
```

Here are my previous two solutions.

```
def count_vowels(sentence):
    a = sentence.count("a")
    b = sentence.count("e")
    c = sentence.count("i")
    d = sentence.count("o")
    e = sentence.count("i")
    return (a+b+c+d+e)



def count_vowels_iterative(sentence):
    a_ = 0
    e_ = 0
    i_ = 0
    o_ = 0
    u_ = 0
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        if "a" == sentence[i]:
            a_ = a_ + 1
        elif "e" == sentence[i]:
            e_ = e_ + 1
        elif "i" == sentence[i]:
            i_ = i_ + 1
        elif "o" == sentence[i]:
            o_ = o_ + 1
        elif "u" == sentence[i]:
            u_ = u_ + 1
        else:
            continue
    return (a_ + e_ + i_ + o_ + u_)
```

Comment: Hint: what happens when your recursion reaches the end of the string and you try to test `sentence[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no base case. The function will keep recursing until `sentence` is empty, in which case your first if statement will cause that index error.

You should first of all check if sentence is empty, and if so return 0

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten things up quite a bit:

```
def count_vowels_recursive(sentence):
    # this base case is needed to stop the recursion
    if not sentence:  
        return 0
    # otherwise, sentence[0] will raise an exception for the empty string
    return (sentence[0] in "aeiou") + count_vowels_recursive(sentence[1:])
    # the boolean expression `sentence[0] in "aeiou"` is cast to an int for the addition
```

Comment: You can shorten it even more: `return (sentence[0] in "aeiou") + count_vowels_recursive(sentence[1:])` (Python counts False as 0 and True as 1).

Comment: True, even though this coercion is probably even more obscure to the beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def count_vowels_recursive(s, count):
   if not s:
      return count
   else:
       new_count = count
       if s[0] in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
          new_count += 1
       return count_vowels_recursive(s[1:], new_count)
```